# return only item in a `Frozenset`

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a situation in my code where there is a `Frozenset` which contains a single number (e.g. `Frozenset([5])`). What I want to do is get that value into a variable. What is the pythonic way to do this?

Since you can iterate over a `Frozenset`, I have already tried to do it like this: `var = next(myFrozenSet)` but it does not work, since a `Frozenset` is not actually an iterator.
I also tried to use `myFrozenSet.pop()`, but this is not attribute of `Frozensets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an iterator with the [`iter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

```
element = next(iter(some_frozen_set))
```

This is the most efficient method of getting a single element out of a `frozenset`; all other methods involve creating another container first (like a set or list), which is more costly than creating an iterator.

Comment: In another place I want to reverse iterate over the `frozenset`, is the best way to do this by creating a container first?

Comment: @micsthepick: sets have no order, so there is no forward or reverse direction. You'd *have* to create an ordered container for the elements first, imparting some kind of sorting in the process.